# How to span wallpaper over 2 monitors in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, desktop-background

I am trying to get a wallpaper shown over 2 monitors for Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell desktop environment. I went to `Tweaks` --> `Appearance` --> `Background` --> `Adjustment` and changed the setting from "Zoom" to "Spanned".

However, the wallpaper appears out of alignment. Below is the outcome from PrintScreen.

[image]

In reality, visually the right monitor image is shifted up and you dont' see the 2 black zones.

[image: error]

**How can I correct the appearance of the wallpaper?** I am using an NVidia graphic card.

The wallpaper is correctly spanned in the gdm login screen. No alignment issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue is to go to `Settings` --> `Device` --> `Display` --> `Display Arrangement`. Here, mouse click onto Display `1` (display on the right) and shift it upwards to align both Display `1` & `2`. Click on `Apply` button to save the change.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use an image editor like GIMP to split your image into two halves.

Then you can set the background image for each display independently.

You should also make sure that your displays are correctly aligned.

If the displays are not the same resolution, you will need to accommodate for that.